# Switching between autonomous control and keyboard control in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

***I want to write a C++ program to switch the control from keyboard to autonomous and vice-versa. Will it be feasible in ROS?***

Because, my program need to communicate through two packages namely move_base and brown_remotelab (http://wiki.ros.org/brown_remotelab). I can’t visualize the whole scenario and it’s complexity.

**Can you give some insight about the situation and some idea to design the program?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105666/switching-between-autonomous-control-and-keyboard-control-in-ros/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-11-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS already provides tools for that.

[Mux](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux) will let you switch an output topic from multiple incoming topics by calling a service, basically what you were asking for.

What might be more convenient to use is the [cmd_vel_mux](http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux). It lets you define a couple of sources for a cmd_vel topic that are ordered by priorities. From the active topics the one with highest priority is used. Usually one puts autonomous control at the lowest and uses a teleop setup that is silent when no commands are issued. In this case the switch to autonomy will happen automatically when teleop is not used.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-12-03**:
Thanks for your reply.
I have one doubt. Are you sure that even if in maze; ROS can produce an effective autonomous plan to achieve a certain goal? Will there be any chance that the Robot halts at various junction like L, T or +?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-12-03**:
Till now I have not achieved autonomous navigation, so I am aware of only cmd_vel topic by teleop. After achieving High level navigation, will there be any auto_cmd_vel (auto tends for autonomous) by move_base node?
Again cmd_vel_mux is bang on target and if I can use it then it will be very useful for me, but as I am using USARSimROS (for P3AT robot) and my knowledge regarding kobuki_node is very less. I if cmd_vel of teleop and cmd_vel of move_base must publish messages to mux node; I think. Do, I need to write custom code to link move_base node to mux node?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-04**:
This works out of the box. It's intended for the turltebots/kobuki, but independent. The only thing it does is automatically switch between the cmd_vel topics. Usually you'd just remap them accordingly, e.g. move_base's will go to /cmd_vel_mux/autonomy_cmd_vel or something like that.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-04**:
Something like autonomous plans to achieve goals in a maze is out of the scope for this question and a very different problem. Open a new question if you want to inquire about some capabilities of the navigation stack.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-12-04**:
ok.. Thanks sir @dornhege

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-12-08**:
One more question @dornhege; can I assign two different priorities(at time instant t1, priority p1 and in another time instant t2, priority p2) to the same cmd_vel topic?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-09**:
I don't know. Maybe just try it?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-01-29**:
@dornhege cmd_vel_mux (http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux) is written for Groovy/hydro. I am using Fuerte. So can I use this package directly by simply modifying subscriber and publisher? Is there any problem with communication between nodelet and normal nodes? I have seen in here http://www.isep.ipp.pt/roswiki/kobuki(2f)Tutorials(2f)Kobuki(27)s(20)Control(20)System.html
Where mobile_base has to be a nodelet as well. PLEASE REPLY

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-20**:
@dornhege, I have used cmd_vel_mux, but I have not achieved the proper behavior as the package summary CLAIMED. I have included a question (http://answers.ros.org/question/126391/nodelet-usage-and-its-role-in-designing-a-complex-controller/) and later part of the question tackles how the changing of PRIORITy and TIMEOUT parameter does not improve the performance. Do you have any suggestion?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-20**:
Please open a new question for specific problems.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-20**:
@dornhege, I added a new question; you may look over here http://answers.ros.org/question/155326/proper-working-of-cmd_vel_mux-for-velocity-multiplexing/